# Command not found: cargo

Tags: rust

I'm getting started with using Emacs as a basic IDE for which I have `rust-mode` installed.

I can execute `cargo test` from the Terminal, but when I try this in Emacs with:

```
M-x compile
cargo test
```

I get an error:

```
cargo test --verbose
zsh:1: command not found: cargo

Compilation exited abnormally with code 127
```

In my `~/.config/emacs/init.el` I have:

```
(setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ":/usr/local/go/bin:~/.local/share/go/bin:~/.local/share/rust/cargo/bin"))
```

which reflects correctly when I do a `M-x getenv PATH`:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:~/.local/share/go/bin:~/.local/share/rust/cargo/bin
```

The last location in the above path has `cargo` among other executables.

How can I ensure that `cargo` is found by emacs ?

---

Edit:

I'm running Emacs 29.1 as a GUI application on Debian Testing (Trixie)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emacs searches the path in the [exec-path](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Subprocess-Creation.html) variable for executable commands. It inherits it from the 'parent environment'. If cargo is available in the terminal, then you will find that when starting Emacs from that same terminal, Emacs will be able to find the `cargo` command. However, you are probably starting Emacs via the desktop shortcut.

There are multiple possible solutions:

- add the cargo path to something like `.profile` (read about difference between `.bashrc` and `.profile`, and other options for your OS or, probably, GNU/Linux distribution).
- add the cargo path to `exec-path` directly using `add-to-list` (read docsctring of `add-to-list` if you would like to append to the `exec-path`).
- use the [exec-path-from-shell](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell) package

The `process-environment` is the environment sub-processes (started from Emacs) inherit (see its docsctring or [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Subprocess-Creation.html)).

Comment: I moved environment variables from .zshrc to .zshenv and installed and configured the exec-path-from-shell package

Comment: Actually when I deep it, `exec-path-from-shell` is not required if `PATH` is set correctly - in `.zshenv`, which also reflects in `M-x getenv PATH`.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it's best to decide on 1 of the above solutions and stick to that one (unless you have some very good reason not too).